# Dimension of global attractor - How to find it?

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have a very general question.
I have a dynamical system and found a global attractor, how can I determine the dimension of that global attractor?

Do you have helpful hints, links etc.?
I sit in front of this task and do not know where to start. I only found very much very special articles (rather concerned with pde's) that could not help me resp. I did not understand.

Maybe thats too difficult for me at all...